# PC POST beep when boot up

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, post

I have one personal computer that when randomly not able to boot up (like few times in a week), every time it short-beeped once and not able to boot, so i searched online and found that, one short beep is something related to dram.

Few times i removed my ram and plug it back, it is able to boot, i did a memtest and it shows that both of my rams are fine, what could be the problem, ram slot of the motherboard? How can i investigate?

[Short clip of the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dkVt7XgmZvMeXoKMbeAR2S9wOiA0hK47/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Please post the PC or motherboard model

Comment: @Moab added motherboard and bios information.

Comment: Is there a bios upgrade available from Asrock?

Comment: @Moab if there is an upgrade, should i do it? from bios itself don't have direct upgrade, i have to download it, copy it into pen drive, and run from bios

Comment: I would, but there are risks with bios upgrades.

Comment: @Moab, i think worth a try, if anything happens, and i rollback to the current version, it should be fine right?